# How do we prove that uniform convergence preserves boundedness?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, bounded-variation

Let $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of functions from one metric space $(X,d_{X})$ to
another $(Y,d_{Y})$, and suppose that this sequence converges uniformly to another function $f:X\to Y$. If the functions $f_{n}$ are bounded on $X$ for each $n$, then the limiting function $f$ is also bounded on $X$.

**My solution**

If $f_{n}\to f$ uniformly, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a natural number $N\geq 1$ such that for every $x\in X$ we have that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f_{n}(x),f(x)) < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Since each $f_{n}$ is bounded, we have that $f_{n}(X)\subseteq B(y_{0},r_{n})$.

But I do not know how to proceed from here. Could someone help me to solve this?

**Edit**

As suggested in the comments, we have that
\begin{align*}
d_{Y}(y_{0},f(x)) \leq d_{Y}(y_{0},f_{n}(x)) + d_{Y}(f_{n}(x),f(x)) \leq r_{n} + \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Thus if we set $\varepsilon = 1$, there is a natural number $N_{1}\geq 1$ such that for every $x\in X$ one has that
\begin{align*}
d_{Y}(y_{0},f(x)) \leq r_{N_{1}} + 1
\end{align*}
That is to say, $f(x)\in B(y_{0},r_{N_{1}}+1)$ for every $x\in X$, and we are done.

Comment: Fix $\epsilon = 1$ and apply triangle inequality

Comment: The triangle inequality implies $f(X) \subset B(y_0, r_N + \epsilon)$

Comment: $|f| = |f - f_n + f_n|$ Apply triangle inequality. Can you finish?

Comment: Thanks all of you for the contribution! I have edited my question in order to include my new attempt.